# Hide Received information from Email when using SwiftMailer and SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer, email-headers

I have a VPS hosting and I am using SwiftMailer to send emails using an smtp from another hosting.
When I send an email to the user the source mail contains my VPS ip address and domain in headers, like the following below:

```
Received: from [ip.ip.ip.ip] (port=•port• helo=mydomain.name) by ....
```

I was able to hide the domain from swiftmailer using `setLocalDomain`, but wasn't able to change the IP address even when using `setSourceIp` on SwiftMailer.

Hint: I don't have access to smtp hosting, I have just my VPS and smtp credentials.

Comment: Why do you want to hide it, exactly? Surely it's better if users can see that the mail came from your server legitimately. Or is your server not legitimate?!

Comment: @ADyson actually it is for a client request, and this is a good point but I investigated very well and every thing seems OK.

Comment: I'd suggest finding out why the client deems this necessary.  I'm not sure there's a good way to do it

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway